# MySql Database profiling and checking its result using perl

Tags: database, perl, profiling

I want to see how much time my query taking to execute using perl. Here is my work till now

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $driver = "mysql";
my $database = "employee";
my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:database=$database";
my $userid = "root";
my $password = "****";

my $sql_statement;
my $sth;
my $data;
my $row;

my $dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $userid, $password ) or die $DBI::errstr;
my $foo = "SET profiling=on;"."\n"."SELECT * FROM employee;"."\n"."SHOW PROFILES;";
open my $fh, "<", \$foo;
binmode $fh, ":encoding(utf8)";

    while ($sql_statement = <$fh>)
    {
            $data = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql_statement) or die "issue is : $dbh->errstr";
    }

    my $retirement_date;
    if (scalar @$data)
    {
            $retirement_date  = strftime( "%F %H:%M:%S", localtime(time() - @$data[0]));
    }
    print $retirement_date;
```

but I am not getting any result.

expected output should be like this

```
5   15.86296022 SELECT * from employee;
```

where 5 is query id, 15.86296022 is execution time and last query.

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: MySQL has following [webpage](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/performance/index.html) dedicated to optimization queries.

Comment: There are a number of [MySQL optimization tools](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1SQJL_enCA861CA861&sxsrf=ALeKk01boMFGl568WJJyIvWdBfOYoFBrLA%3A1599755805409&ei=HVZaX4i6GJL9-gTB7a_wBA&q=mysql+optimization+tools&oq=mysql+optimzaton&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAxgDMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANMgQIABANOgQIABBHOgIIADoECAAQQzoHCAAQFBCHAjoHCAAQChDLAToFCAAQywE6BggAEBYQHjoECAAQClCENFi0SWCoaWgBcAF4AIABe4gBpAaSAQQxMC4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab) available.

Comment: Documentation [How to Use MySQL Query Profiling](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mysql-query-profiling).

Comment: Documentation [Query Profiling Using Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-query-profiling.html).

Answer (score 2):

You're not getting any result because you're misunderstanding the data structure you're getting back from `selectall_arrayref()`. It's an arrayref of arrayrefs - so you need to look two levels deep in it in order to get the actual data.

I replaced the second part of your code with this:

while ($sql_statement = <$fh>) {
warn "$sql_statement\n";
$data = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql_statement) or die "issue is : $dbh->errstr";
print join(' | ', @$_), "\n" for @$data;
}

And when I run it, I get this:

```
$ perl dbprofile
SET profiling=on;

DBD::mysql::db selectall_arrayref failed: fetch() without execute() at dbprofile line 25, <$fh> line 1.
SELECT * FROM employee;

1 | Fred | 2020-09-09
2 | Bill | 2035-06-23
3 | Jane | 2058-03-11
SHOW PROFILES;
1 | 0.00027717 | SELECT * FROM employee
```

I'm not sure what's going on with the "fetch() without execute()" error and I don't have time to investigate it now. But you can see all of your data - including the profiling information.

Answer (score 2):

Please see if following demo code provides desired output

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# vim: ai:ts=4:sw=4
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DBI;
use Config::General;

my($dsn,$dbh,$sth,$query,$rv);

my $conf    = Config::General->new( "$ENV{HOME}/.my.cnf" );
my %config  = $conf->getall;

# Keep password inside code
$config{password} = 'your_password_here';

$dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=$config{database};host=$config{host};port=$config{port}";
$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $config{user}, $config{password},
    {
        RaiseError => 1,
        mysql_enable_utf8 => 1
    });

$query  = "SET PROFILING=on";
$sth    = $dbh->prepare($query) or die $dbh->errstr;
$rv     = $sth->execute() or die $dbh->errstr;
#say $DBI::errstr if $rv < 0;

my $db_table = 'your_db_table_here';
$query  = "SELECT * FROM $db_table";
$sth    = $dbh->prepare($query) or die $dbh->errstr;
$rv     = $sth->execute() or die $dbh->errstr;
#say $DBI::errstr if $rv < 0;

$query  = "SHOW PROFILES";
$sth    = $dbh->prepare($query) or die $dbh->errstr;
$rv     = $sth->execute() or die $dbh->errstr;
#say $DBI::errstr if $rv < 0;
while( my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref ) {
    say join("\t",@{$row});
}

$query  = "SET PROFILING=off";
$sth    = $dbh->prepare($query) or die $dbh->errstr;
$rv     = $sth->execute() or die $dbh->errstr;
#say $DBI::errstr if $rv < 0;

$sth->finish();
$dbh->disconnect();
```

Sample of `$ENV{HOME}/.my.cnf` file

```
[mysql]
host=yout_db_host_name
user=your_db_user_name
database=your_db_name
default-character-set=utf8
port=3306
```

Sample of output

```
1       0.0014745       SELECT * FROM new_movies
```

Comment: can you please suggest me how to get same output from database itself. I want to call same "SHOW PROFILES" in mysql and it gives me same result.

Comment: @someone - your queston is not clear. I assume that you work with DB from command line. Issue SQL command `SET PROFILING=on`, now run set of SQL commands, to see profiles issue SQL command `SHOW PROFILES`, once you finish issue command `SET PROFILING=off`.

Comment: I am running a perl script for query execution. But after executing 'SHOW PROFILES' using perl, when I am checking DB from command line, SHOW PROFILES gives empty set. I think there is some grant issue and I am not able to identify that.

Comment: Please read [13.7.7.30 SHOW PROFILE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html), [Chapter 26 MySQL Performance Schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/performance-schema.html). Your grand issue is that you do not read documentation.